# Get number of sole bit in bitfield

Tags: c

I have a 32-bit bitfield where a single bit is set. How can I get the number of this bit (as int or something)?

Examples (using 8 bit for brevity):

```
Input              Desired output
0x01 / 00000001 -> 0
0x04 / 00000100 -> 2
0x08 / 00001000 -> 3
0x00 / 00000000 -> undefined/whatever
0x06 / 00000110 -> undefined/whatever
```

I'm looking for succinct and readable code or common library functions, not for the most clever or best performing solution.

Comment: http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/debruijn.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a compiler builtin for this. **gcc** and **clang** support this:

> Built-in Function: `int __builtin_clz(unsigned int x)`
>
> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in `x`, starting at the most significant bit position. If `x` is `0`, the result is undefined.

```
int bit_index32(unsigned x) {
    return 31 - __builtin_clz(x);
}
```

For a more portable solution, you can use a simple loop:

```
int bit_index32(unsigned x) {
    int n = 0;
    while (x > 1) { n++; x >>= 1; }
    return n;
}
```

A faster one with just 5 tests instead of up to 31:

```
int bit_index32(unsigned x) {
    int n = 0;
    if (x > 0xFFFF) { n += 16; x >>= 16; }
    if (x > 0xFF)   { n +=  8; x >>=  8; }
    if (x > 0xF)    { n +=  4; x >>=  4; }
    if (x > 0x3)    { n +=  2; x >>=  2; }
    if (x > 0x1)    { n +=  1; x >>=  1; }
    return n;
}
```

Since `v` is a power of 2, the index is the number of bits in `v-1`, which can be computes without tests:

```
int bit_index32(unsigned v) {
    v--;
    v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
}
```

Another branchless one that only works for powers of 2:

```
int bit_index32(unsigned v) {
    return !!(v & 0xAAAAAAAA)
         | !!(v & 0xCCCCCCCC) << 1
         | !!(v & 0xF0F0F0F0) << 2
         | !!(v & 0xFF00FF00) << 3
         | !!(v & 0xFFFF0000) << 4;
}
```

More fun at Sean Anderson's [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html)!

Answer (score 2):

Shift one bit at a time until its in the low position and increment a counter each time.

```
int get_bit_num(uint32_t n)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (n>1) {
      n >>= 1;
      count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I thought the same. How else would someone go about checking a specific bit other than iterating over each bit..

Comment: @Irelia The same argument could be made for `popcount()`.